# Is EF.SaveChanges atomic using Cosmos DB provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Is SaveChanges atomic using Cosmos DB across multiple documents?

If it's not, is there any alternative to implement atomic operations?

Comment: Can't say it for certain but I doubt it. Transactions in Cosmos are limited to a partition. As there's no way to scope the `SaveChanges`  to a partition or instruct it to leverage transactions I don't think EF uses them. It's also a relatively new feature. The Cosmos SDK allows you to use them in C# using `CreateTransactionalBatch`. A stored procedure will also work but requires a fair bit of custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Operations on a single document are atomic in a single Container.

> **Alternative:** You may conduct an atomic set of several operations within a single partition within a single container if you utilize a
> Stored Procedure or  the new Transactional Batch support to create
> atomic groups of operation, [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-how-to-do-bulk-and-transactional-batch-operations-with-the-azure-cosmos-db-net-sdk/).

There are no atomic operations that can be performed across several containers or different divisions of a single container. This has nothing to do with the dev languages, rather that's how Cosmos DB service operates in this manner.

Comment: So the SaveChanges call is not atomic. This is a HUGE difference with relational db providers that I see a lot of folks are not aware of